Bug in IndexOf with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase in .NET 5 and above?
I found a weird issue with .NET 5 and above with the IndexOf method.
I have two strings that are equals with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
string.Equals("eﬆ", "est", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // returns True

Since ﬆ by Unicode specs is equivalent to "ST".
Using IndexOf like in this example
"eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // returns 0

returns 0, which is expected, as we saw that both strings are equivalent under InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
Although, when we add space (" ") to the source string
" eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // returns -1

the function returns -1! Which is unexpected. We found out that we get -1 for .NET 5 and above (including .NET 8).
Getting 0 and -1, respectively, is unexpected.
To summarize:
"eﬆ".IndexOf("est", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // 0 ✅
" eﬆ".IndexOf("est", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // -1 (Why???)
" ﬆ".IndexOf("st", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // 1 ✅

Is this a bug in the .NET IndexOf implementation? Any workaround that solves it? (Turn off ICU is not acceptable)

The oldest supported .NET Core version is 6 and the culture support is better that .NET Framework 4.8's, using the ICU rules/libraries instead of Windows libraries. by Unicode specs is equivalent to "st". which specs? Such things are typically culture-specific

@PanagiotisKanavos But we see that without the space it returns 0 and says that both strings are equivalent, and with additional character it says -1 (not found). The unicode specs is SpecialCasing

The change to ICU is documented in .NET Globalization and ICU. The change was made to ensure that .NET Core code behaves the same on Windows and Linux. .NET 5+ are .NET Core versions, not .NET Framework versions.

@PanagiotisKanavos still, "eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) is 0, " eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) is -1. I'm aware that the .NET uses better culture support. But the expected results are both -1 and -1 or 0 and 1, respectivly

What in this entire document says that st is equivalent to "ﬆ" ? In Python 3 "st" in "eﬆ" returns false, both on Windows and Ubuntu.

@PanagiotisKanavos Because you use case dependent comparison. The uppercase of ﬆ is ST, try "ﬆ".upper() == "ST"

You can use the System.Globalization.UseNls = true configuration option and get the happy answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

I'm not arguing. It's hard to explain why a spec works the way it does when the spec is missing. .NET 5 started using ICU. That's a fact. Of course I used case-dependent comparison, we're comparing the lowercase text you provided. You're asking why the Unicode 0xFB06 character isn't the same as s followed by t. That's where normalization comes in. If you use the KC or KD normalization forms ﬆ does become s and t, both in .NET Core and Python. That normalization isn't performed by default

I think you missed the point. I want to use ICU! I just say that is unexpected to get "eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0, " eﬆ".IndexOf("est",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1

You can also get the old behavior with <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization> in the .csproj but that can lead to issues when deployed on Linux, or when people start asking why this application behaves differently from other .NET Core applications

@PanagiotisKanavos I am using ICU and DON'T want to disable it. My question is specifically about IndexOf. Why adding additional characters makes the IndexOf to miss the string?

Interestingly, without the "e" it behaves differently: " ﬆ".IndexOf("st",  System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) gives 1

@KlausGütter this is great example! I don't know what is wrong with the IndexOf...

Nothing is wrong, that's how it's supposed to work due to different collation strengths!!! And I've upvoted that question, but completely forgot about it.

@PanagiotisKanavos please see my updated question. Can you explain each row in the summarized code?

@nrofis Can you try the proposed solution in the question Panagiotis linked above? StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)

Also, " eﬆ" gives -1 if you replace the space with any letters from the English alphabet: "ccceﬆ".IndexOf("est", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) => -1. But if you use some other letters (Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, Latin with umlauts), it gives proper result again: "ćććeﬆ".IndexOf("est", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) => 3. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kkn6aS

If it was a bug then the bug would be in the Windows ICUUC.DLL implementation rather than .NET itself.

@Fildor I don't think we can use the StringComparer object in the IndexOf method

Yep, just figured that out myself :(
